# Yii2 - change DataPicker widget options by SwitchInput widget

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

DataPicker widget:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'dateSale')->textInput()->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'name' => 'dp_4',
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
        'disabled' => true
        ]) ?>
```

SwitchInput widget:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput()->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
    'name' => 'status_11',
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => 'function(event, state) {
            if (state == 0){
                $("#vehicle-datesale").dp4("disabled", "false");
            }
            else {
                $("#vehicle-datesale").dp4("disabled", "true");
            }   
        }',
    ]
]) ?>
```

Why doesn't the above work, and how should I do this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to 'DatePicker' depending on the status 'SwitchInput' (0 or 1) become enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change code in `SwitchInput` widget.

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput()->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
        'name' => 'status_11',
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => 'function(event, state) {
                if (state == 0 || state == false){
                    $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", "false");
                }
                else {
                    $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", "true");
                } 

            }',
        ]
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: any reaction after switching

Answer (score 0):

your code is working; only change:

```
 if (state == 0 || state == false){
                $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", "false");
            }
            else {
                $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", "true");
            }
```

by

```
 if (state == 0 || state == false){
                $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", false);
            }
            else {
                $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'dateSale').'").attr("disabled", true);
            }
```